# How to change second drop-down value based first drop-down selection?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a two drop downs namely `Min Price` and `Max Price`, i want to change the second drop-down value based on the first selection.

Say example `1st drop-down selection is 100 means, 2nd drop-down value should be greater than the 100, if it is 200 in 1st, value of 2nd should be greater than 200`

Any idea in jQuery or js?

Comment: Hi Ricky i don't know how to do this, please guide me.

Comment: I asked that because it is considered a good practice to show that you have tried something before you ask for help otherwise it just sounds as if you are asking for someone to do your homework... But since this is such a popular question I guess you have 5 implementations already =) pick one ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest i could think of ( this allows you to go back in your choices, you can select 400 and then 200 and everything works )

```
<select id='min'>
<option value='100'>100</option>
<option value='200'>200</option>
<option value='300'>300</option>
<option value='400'>400</option>
</select>
<select id='max'>
<option value='100'>100</option>
<option value='200'>200</option>
<option value='300'>300</option>
<option value='400'>400</option>
</select>​

var removed;

$('#min').change( function() {
    var value = this.value;
    $('#max').prepend(removed);
    var toKeep = $('#max option').filter( function( ) {
        return parseInt(this.value, 10) >= parseInt( value, 10);
    } );
    removed =  $('#max option').filter( function( ) {
        return parseInt(this.value, 10) < parseInt( value, 10);
    } );
    $('#max').html(toKeep);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NjLNF/2/

EDIt - added parseInt() as per comment

Comment: hi its working fine upto 100 to 900, after that(1000,2000,..) its not working properly check this [http://jsfiddle.net/NjLNF/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/NjLNF/1/)

Comment: @LearneR yes you are right, because you need to parseInt() the values http://jsfiddle.net/NjLNF/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery and the change function.  If you id for the first dropdown is drop1 the it would be $("#drop1").change(function() { .. put your function here to populate the second drop down ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#first_dd').change(function(){
var dd_val=$(this).val();
var options = "";
$('#second_dd').html('');
for(var i=parseInt(dd_val+1);i<=END-LIMIT;i++)
{
$('#second_dd').append('<option value='+i+'>'+i+'</option>');
}
});
```

I have not test it in browser. Consider the systex, just follow the logic.

Comment: Yes, but what if the user chooses an high value for the first dropdown and then chanhges his mind and want a lower one?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
        $("#one").change(function (e) {
            $("#two").empty();

            var options =
            $("#one option").filter(function(e){
                return $(this).attr("value") > $("#one option:selected").val();
            }).clone();

            $("#two").append(options);
        });
    });
```

Comment: And if you want to go back?I mean if you first select 4 in the first dropdown and then one?

Comment: The script is not changing (affecting) values of `#one` dropdown here, just cloning values greater than `#one` to `#two`

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to Min Price drop down then loop through the values of Max Price drop down till you find a value greater than the selected Min Price dropdown. Something like this

```
$('#minPrice').change(function(){
    var minVal = $('#minPrice option:selected').val();
     $('#maxPrice option').each(function(){
          if(minVal < $(this).val()){
             $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
             return false;
          }
     });
});
```